# How to specify reference path recursive in Visual Studio Project

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I have a csproj in which I need to specify a reference path recursive.

ex:
..\Reference Path\Entlib\;..\Reference Path\Netonsoft.Json\

Instead of specifying all sub directories in the folder as above . I just want to specify a parent direcotry such as

..\Reference Path

so it directly resolves all dlls in sub folder

Comment: Do you mean `..\Reference Path\**\*.dll` ?

Comment: Yes something similar. But trying that is not working